# getArgument() in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to retrieve an argument in dialogflow's Fulfillment.

When I use `let name = agent.getArgument('name');` to retrieve the argument, I get the following error `TypeError: agent.getArgument is not a function`.

`agent` is `const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });` (default), and other functions such as `agent.add()` work perfectly fine.

I'm using Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/docs/WebhookClient.md#WebhookClient+parameters) there is no existing `getArgument()` method.

Maybe you are looking for [agent.parameters](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/docs/WebhookClient.md#webhookclientparameters--object) ?

[Actions and Parameters](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.
Also, I feel dumb now.